# php_ffmpeg not working

Tags: php, ffmpeg-php

i've installed the php_ffmpeg extension on my xampp under c:/xampp/php/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll
- according to phpinfo() it seems to be properly installed.
however - when trying to create a thumbnail from a video it is executing without errors, but i'm not getting any image .. the apache error log is showing: command "ffmpeg" is either mis-spelled or couldn't be found.
my code is:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg  -i myvideo.flv -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 150x150 -an thumbnail.jpg";
exec($cmd);
```

any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing a shell command (`ffmpeg -i ...`) outside PHP, without using the PHP extension `ffmpeg-php`. That extension provides some functions to PHP, see [ffmpeg-php API documentation](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/).

If you insist on using the ffmpeg command-line program, take a look at the [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) project. Windows binaries can be downloaded [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). The documentation for the commandline application `ffmpeg` can be reached from [here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html). If necessary, use the full path to the `ffmpeg` binary:

```
$ffmpeg = "C:\\Program Files\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe";
$cmd = "$ffmpeg  -i myvideo.flv -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 150x150 -an thumbnail.jpg";
exec($cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `ffmpeg` installed or it's not in your path. What you're doing here has nothing to do with the `php_ffmpeg` extension. You're attempting to execute the `ffmpeg` binary.

See the [API documentation](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/) for php_ffmpeg if you wish to try using it.